# How do I access a super classes instance var?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a very simple use case that is giving me difficulty:

Here's some code:

```
@interface Foo : UIViewController {
    id myVar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id myVar;
@end    

@interface Bar : Foo {}                     
@end
```

If and when I'm im writing code in Bar.m and trying to access myVar in such format as:

```
self.myVar or [self myVar]
```

The compiler complains that myVar is something not a structure or union. myVar is synthesized in Foo. Why can't I access it in the child class?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to import Bar.h in Bar.m, and Foo.h in Bar.h?